# DELETE fails with "foreign key constraint failed" even though ON DELETE CASCADE is specified

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm working on C# project and I'm using system.data.sqlite. I have 3(relevent) tables created with

```
create table students(
    _id integer primary key,
    fname text not null,
    lname text not null,
    st_number integer not null unique,
    level integer not null,
    class integer,
FOREIGN KEY (class) REFERENCES classes(_id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
FOREIGN KEY (level) REFERENCES levels(_id) on delete cascade on update cascade)

create table payments(
    _id integer primary key,
    student integer not null,
    amount integer not null,
    recieve_date text not null,
    type text not null,
foreign key(student) references students(st_number) on update cascade on delete cascade)

create table signups(
    _id integer primary key,
    student integer not null,
    service integer not null,
foreign key(student) references students(st_number) on update cascade on delete cascade,
foreign key(service) references services(_id) on update cascade on delete cascade)
```

now when I try to delete a record from students table I get a FK violation error while I'm expecting it to delete all connected entries from payments and signups table.

It might be connected with the way I turn on FK support in sqlite. I turn it on in my connection string

```
@"Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;foreign_keys = 1;"
```

Sorry for the long create statements. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `I get a FK violation error` Can you give the **exact** exception details?

Comment: @mjwills SQLite's error message for a FK constraint violation does not contain details.

Comment: Please provide some sample data. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: `SQLite's error message for a FK constraint violation does not contain details.` Can you provide a screenshot of it perhaps then?

Comment: @mjwillis Do you mean somethink like this?http://tinypic.com/r/jhzb4z/9

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/23515050/34092 help?

Comment: @CL I populate the db with random data for development. Here is my whole db https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Z6lHDehSMfS29jU2wzd2FWQWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mjwills Well apparently you could omit the pragma and add it to connection string. And certainly the FK constraints are enforced(because w/o it I don't have any FK enforcement) but it doesn't cascade like its supposed to do

Comment: What version of SQLite are you running?

Comment: @mjwills System.data.sqlite 1.0.105.2 which uses sqlite 3.19.3

Comment: @CL you could view the db with the firefox add-on "sqlite manager". You could turn FK on in DB settings tab(select on-click change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out another table was referring to payments and its FK didn't have cascade.  Added that and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
@"Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;foreign_keys = 1;"
```

looks to be a typo, and should be changed to:

```
@"Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;foreign keys = 1;"
```

*I changed the `_` to a blank space.*